# Comparing Characters in Swift

Tags: compare, character, swift

```
let a:Character = "a"  // Would not really be a literal in my app...
let b:Character = "b"  // ...but this illustrates the issue
let compare = a == b
```

The compiler complains: Could not find an overload for == that accepts the supplied arguments.

This despite the fact that if you right-click on Character you can easily find this declaration

```
func ==(lhs: Character, rhs: Character) -> Bool
```

Any suggestions? I can work around by assigning the Characters to Strings and doing a String compare, BUT I am iterating over thousands of Characters. Surely there is a Swift Way.

Comment: is that all the code you have? It's working fine for me in the playground. Maybe restart xcode?

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Seems Swift keeps thinking the `==` operator I'm applying on a `Character` to a single-character string literal is actually one of my custom overloaded `==` operators on completely different types, and complains that it can't convert `Character` to my other class. Smells like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 6):

This should actually work. Here's the output of your supplied code.

[image: Code above shown in an Xcode playground]

Comment: Works in the Playground for me too. But not in a source code file.

Comment: False alarm. Problem went away when I restarted Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This works w/o a problem:

```
  3> let a: Character = "a"
a: Character = SmallRepresentation {
  SmallRepresentation = 9223372036854775649
}
  4> let b: Character = "b"
b: Character = SmallRepresentation {
  SmallRepresentation = 9223372036854775650
}
  5> let compare = (a == b)
compare: (Bool) = false
  6> let compare2 = a == b
compare2: Bool = false
```

Comment: Correct. It works in the Playground but not in a .swift code file.

Comment: How does it fail in a .swift file?

Comment: See below. False alarm. But... a Q. What environment were you using where you had the number> prompt and the enum details? My Playground environment looks like the one below, from Brendan Lim.

Comment: I'm using the _Swift_ REPL - the Terminal/Shell executable called 'swift' from .../Xcode6.../Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift

Comment: Ah thank you; I suspected there was a Terminal app too. BTW, FWIW I have had a few Xcode fails where a compiler error message appears for VALID reasons but refuses to go away when error is fixed. That's why they call it beta, I guess!